# Add On Specific Time Line From a Date In A Database?

Tags: php

Here is my code. I'm trying to add on $Rows['howfar'] which in this case. Lets say it's 2.

So I'm trying to add on two weeks to my date which is currently in my database:

```
//$Rows['howfar'] = 2 weeks for example.
    $NextDate = $Rows['Date'], strtotime("+{$Rows['howfar']} weeks"));
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Syntax for strtotime() function can be found here - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php take note of the second argument, the position of brackets, and how many brackets you're using

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm aware of the syntax, but i'm pulling out a date from a database and adding on a time interval

Comment: Are you wanting a textual date or unix timestamp in return?

Comment: If you're familiar with the syntax, I assume you also know that PHP doesn't have a comma (,) operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$NextDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Rows['Date'] . " +" . $Rows['howfar'] . " weeks"));
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" +"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 28`